# Background colour of table created with HTML/CSS in a VBA-Code

Tags: html, css, excel, vba

I have the following VBA code to create an E-Mail with an HTML-table:

```
Sub Test_EMail3()
    If ExitAll = False Then
        Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, signature As String
        Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OMail
            .Display
            End With
            signature = OMail.HTMLbody
            With OMail
            .To = "test@test.de"
            .Subject = "test"
           .HTMLbody = "<style> th {overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #7a9a01; padding: 5px; border-width: 2px; text-align: left}" _
            & vbCr & "  </style>" _
            & vbCr & "<table><tr>" _
            & vbCr & "<th>Column 1</th>" _
            & vbCr & "<th>Column 2</th>" _
            & vbCr & "</tr><tr>" _
            & vbCr & "<td> Inhalt 1 </td> <td> Inhalt 2 </td>" _
            & vbCr & "</tr><tr>" _
            & vbCr & "<td> Inhalt 1 </td> <td> Inhalt 2 </td>" _
            & vbCr & "</tr></table>"
            End With
        Set OMail = Nothing
        Set OApp = Nothing
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

When I create the E-Mail the table headlines (**Column 1** & **Column 2**) have a green background colour. However, this background colour does not fill the entire cell. There is a small white space on the bottom.

Do you know what I have to change in the HTML, CSS or VBA to fill the entire column in the E-Mail with the background colour?

Comment: Do you want to fill the 'entire column' or just the header itself ? The CSS is set to apply to the `<th>` tag.

Comment: In this case only the <th>

Comment: ok lemme recheck and get back to you

Comment: What Outlook (Office) version? I cannot reproduce this neither using Office 2007 nor using Office 2016. In both there is not a small white space on the bottom of the TH.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it in Office 2013

Comment: If I use anything other than `collapse` i.e `border-collapse: separate|collapse|initial|inherit` then the while line goes but then the two columns are separated

Comment: I use Outlook 2010. When I change border-collapse the same thing as you described happens. It is completely filled with the background colour but the columns are separated which is also not the desired result.

Comment: If you want the entire table: <table bgcolor='red'>

Comment: I would say the `border-collapse` should rather be set for the `table` than only for the `th`. So I would try `<style>table {border-collapse: collapse;} th {overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid black; background-color: #7a9a01; padding: 5px; border-width: 2px; text-align: left}</style>`

Comment: @Axel Richter: I tried it that way but it still does not work.